# show/hide a single div from multiple buttons

Tags: javascript

I have the following js to toggle the show_div class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".slidingDiv").hide();
  $('.show_div').show();

  $('.show_div').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

I have the following html that calls the show_div class:

```
<div>
<a href="#" data-color="red" class="show_div"><img src="../red.png" /></a>
<a href="#" data-color="blue" class="hide_div"><img src="../blue.png" /></a>
</div>
```

When I click on the red.png link, the show_div appears. I can't figure out how to make the show-div hide when I hit the blue.png link.

When I add a class to the blue.png to hide the show_div, it ends up hiding the blue.png instead.  The red.png should toggle show/hide the show_div.  While the blue.png should make sure show_div is hidden.

added code:

```
<div class="slidingDiv">
<div class="show_div">
<a onClick="window.open('listing.html','_blank');">this is red</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 $("a").click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ccMK7/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: argh - I hate it when people who answer seconds after me get the point (:) cause my self-esteem is attached to my SO points, which are really low for this account...lol)... Oh well, I probably shouldn't have gone in to edit. Live long and prosper...

Comment: @BenA.Hilleli Hey bro.. We both answered with 8 seconds difference. I wouldn't have answered, if I saw your post. Anyway +1 for you.

Comment: @Unknown thanks for the help, I am trying to have only the red.png call the show_div.  The blue should close it if it's open.

Comment: @Unknown here is a new fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vB4DT/) When red is selected, it reads this is red and the color red appears.  If I select red again, the color and the text hide.  If green or blue are selected they should make sure the text is hidden before displaying the proper color.

Comment: @need2nobasis You have `data-color` attribute in fiddle. use it to hide text on `anchor` click event. http://jsfiddle.net/vB4DT/1/

Comment: @Unknown this is great thank you.  Could I do something like this:       if($(this).data("color")=="red","lightred","darkred"){

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38819/discussion-between-need2nobasis-and-unknown)

Comment: ;) was just kidding... One of those days, weeks, months... Regards

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a").click(function(){
 $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

You need to attach event to the  tag, there is no event on the hide currently

Comment: thanks for the help, I am trying to have only the red.png call the show_div.  The blue should close it if it's open.